# Azure storage not finding csv file

Tags: c#, azure, csv, azure-storage

I am trying to read a csv file from my azure storage account.
To convert each line into an object and build a list of those objects.
It keeps erring, and the reason is it cant find the file (Blob not found). The file is there, It is a csv file.

[image: File in azure storage]

Error:

> **StorageException: The specified blob does not exist.**
>   BatlGroup.Site.Services.AzureStorageService.AzureFileMethods.ReadCsvFileFromBlobAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string fileName) in AzureFileMethods.cs
>   +
>                   await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);

```
 public async Task<Stream> ReadCsvFileFromBlobAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string fileName)
    {
        // Retrieve reference to a blob (fileName)
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //downloads blob's content to a stream
             await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream;

        }

    }
```

I've made sure the file is public. I can download any text file that is stored there, but none of the csv files.

I am also not sure what format to take it in as I need to iterate through the lines.

I see examples of bringing the whole file down to a temp drive and working with it there but that seems unproductive as then I could just store the file in wwroot folder instead of azure.

What is the most appropriate way to read a csv file from azure storage.

Comment: The most probable reason is that your path is wrong. If the file is in a virtual folder, you need to include the folder(s) into the file name, e.g. `"folder/subfolder/file.jpg"`

Comment: The file path is correct, which is why I can read the text files.

Comment: That's extremely odd then, because the content type shouldn't affect your ability to download it.. It's just metadata.

Comment: @juunas...and its not just that file, I can download all the txt files but none of the csv files

Comment: Is your storage account connections string correct? Could it be pointing to another storage account?

Comment: Can you share the actual link of the blob which you’re not able to download? More than likely the issue is related to the case of the blob name. Blob names are case sensitive.

Comment: I kind of figured out the blob URL and tried to download it. I was able to successfully download it. Then I changed the case of the blob name (e.g. `FirmPnL_tfd_2018.csv` instead of `FirmPnL_TFD_2018.csv`) and was able to reproduce this error. I would suggest checking the value passed in `fileName` variable.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri... call to the method...await ReadCsvFileFromBlobAsync(container, "FirmPnl_TFD_2018.csv"); ...the file name passed is correct

Comment: “l” is lowercase when you’re passing in method while the blob name has it in uppercase.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri...you're right, not sure how I missed that. I changed the file name a few times as I wasn't sure if Azure didn't support underline character.. I know you're the azure expert, what is best way to pull down to iterate through line by line?

Comment: @dinotom I think you should humour everyone and add a line of code before you attempt to create the stream if (blob.Exists()) {... open the stream } else { log.Error...}... If Exists() returns true then there's definitely something fishy, if it returns false then I think you need to think again about your fileNames

Comment: @dinotom I can also add I have similar code to this in a live system and there's no issue with reading and writing CSV files saved in blob storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to iterate through the lines, after you get the memory stream, you can use `StreamReader` to read them line by line.

Sample code as below:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connstr = "your connection string";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connstr);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("t11");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("students.csv");
            string text="";
            string temp = "";
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);

                //remember set the position to 0
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    //read the csv file as per line.
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp=reader.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        text = text + "***" + temp;
                    }

                }


            }

            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.WriteLine("-------");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My csv file:
[image]

The test result:
[image]